# ReactJS: Not able to import Header.js file. ERROR = require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file named index.js where I am trying to import a React header component but am not able to do so. It keeps showing the error that require is not defined.

I tried a lot of Stackoverflow and other pages that suggested to use ES6 Syntax, use modules but still it keeps showing the same error.

`

```
export default function Header(){
    return (
          
            <header>
                <nav className="mynav">
                    <img src="./reactlogo.png" className="myimg"></img>
                    <ul className="mynavitems">
                        <li>Pricing</li>
                        <li> About us</li>
                        <li> Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
    )
}
```

`Above is the file I am trying to import Below is what I am doing to import`

```
import Header from './Header';
```

`

Comment: This is all pretty dependent on your build tooling. What are you using to transpile jsx and bundle?

Comment: I am using VS Code and then Live Server to run it.

Comment: Also, As of now I am just using CDN links to use React as I just started learning it. In the course, it is mentioned as the easy way and not the correct way. Is that what is causing the problem ?

Comment: You'll need some more steps to use jsx and es6 modules in the browser. I'd suggest taking a look at https://parceljs.org/ . I find parcel to be a super easy way to get started w/ this kind of stuff.